# Adding a MID Function to a MATCH Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I have deleted my previous questions on this as it was causing confusion so I am start from scratch to make sure I am being as clear as possible.

Hi All

I am trying to add a MID function to a MATCH Formula as the urls I need to check are over 255 characters.

I have tried to do this as a XMATCH formula but it would not return the row numbers and would crash my system so I have abandoned that option.

The following formula works but not with anything over 255 characters, so I would like to add a MID function so it just checks the middle 255 Characters but I can not get it to work.
This is the formula at the moment -

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,Hosted!B:B,0)),"",MATCH(A2,Hosted!B:B,0))`

Can anyone tell me how and where to add the MID fundtion please?

This is the results tab where urls are added, those with less than 255 characters are pulling the rom number from the "Hosted" sheet correctly (Higlighted in green). Also those that have more than 255 characters return #Value! (Highlighted in Yellow)
[Results Image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWSs5.jpg

This is the Sheets with the list of URL's
[URL List sheet][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whysy.jpg

Any help on this would be massively appreciated as it is driving me crazy and I have been working on this one formula for days!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `XMATCH()`, can't you just switch to `FILTER()`?

For example:

```
=FILTER(ROW(B2:B12),B1:B11=A2)
```

Or, just avoid using the returned position and directly filter whatever you like to. No specific character limit here to hold you back and isntead of a strange construction with `MID()` you do actually have exact matching.

Comment: I dont think so. I am not using XMATCH as it crashed my system several time. 

As I will be using this for thousands of search results it need to mark up the results from the formula so I can then filter based on the results.

Comment: `XMATCH()` crashed your system? Unless you are giving it unreasonable lookup-arrays it should work fine. And the comment you posted perfectly describes the working of `FILTER()`. @m3stripes. Maybe it's worth creating a simplified set of data where you also include your end-goal. I mean, you are now asking going for Y as a means to go from X to Z. There could be way better ways to achieve what you are trying and skip Y alltogether. Are you familiar with what is called the [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I think that is the problem with XMATCH is that I do need it to run through a large ammount of entries in some cases around four thousand. 

I wasnt familiarwith the XY problem but I just had a read through and agree I have defiately fallen into that trap a few times. For example I was focusing on the MATCH solution but tried XMATCH following a suggestion to an earlier question. I am completely open to other solutions but my experience level if very much a beginner.

Comment: @m3stripes, just by reading your comments it's hard to give a definite answer, but I'd recommend you research the `FILTER()` function